# tt0104779 is not defined at HTMLDivElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html

Im facing a problem trying to understand why whenever i clicked a movie that im fetching from the omdb api in order to get a new page that has more details of the movie itself it throws this error: [this is the error im facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YILGA.png)

this is the code: the error comes whenever i try to call the showmoviePost function

```
const moviesList = document.querySelector(".books")
let contrastToggle = false;
let imdbID = ""

async function main() {
    const movies = await fetch ("https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=97f5b4c9&s=spider");
    const moviesData = await movies.json();
   
    moviesList.innerHTML = moviesData.Search.map((movie) => moviesHTML(movie)).join("");
    
   
    
}

main()



function moviesHTML(movie) {
    return `<div class="book" onclick="showMoviePost(${movie.imdbID})">
    <figure class="book__img_wrapper">
        <img class="book_img" src=${movie.Poster} alt="">
    </figure>
    <div class="book__title">
        ${movie.Title} - ${movie.Year}
    </div>
    <div class="book__ratings">
        ${movie.Type}
    </div>
    
</div>`
}


function toggleContrast() {
    contrastToggle = !contrastToggle;
    if (contrastToggle) {
        document.body.classList += " dark-theme"

    } else {
        document.body.classList.remove("dark-theme")
    }
}

//`http://127.0.0.1:5500/user-posts-starter/user.html`
//${window.location.imdbID}

function showMoviePost(imdbID) {
    localStorage.setItem("imdbID", imdbID);
    window.location.href = `http://127.0.0.1:5501/movie.html`
}
```

I have 2 days trying to look for the error through out the internet but i havent found a solution yet

Comment: Can you add your HTML code?

Comment: ```function moviesHTML(movie) {
    return `<div class="book" onclick="showMoviePost(${movie.imdbID})">
    <figure class="book__img_wrapper">
        <img class="book_img" src=${movie.Poster} alt="">
    </figure>
    <div class="book__title">
        ${movie.Title} - ${movie.Year}
    </div>
    <div class="book__ratings">
        ${movie.Type}
    </div>
    
</div>`
}

function HTMLToDOM(htmlString){
    let parsedHtml = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlString, "text/html");
    return parsedHtml;
};

HTMLToDOM(moviesHTML(movie)); ```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the `movie.imdbID` property is a string and not just a number. You would need to quote the parameter to use it as you are but a better option would be to use data attributes and read them from the element in the event handler.

```js
return `<div class="book" data-imdb-id="${movie.imdbID}">...`;
```

You can add a delegated event handler on `moviesList` and check for clicks on your `.book` elements...

```js
moviesList.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const book = e.closest(".book[data-imdb-id]");
  if (book) {
    showMoviePost(book.dataset.imdbId);
  }
});
```

---

Creating HTML strings is fraught with issues around quoting and encoding. I would highly recommend using DOM methods to create elements

```js
const createElement = (type, attributes, ...children) => {
  const elt = document.createElement(type);
  Object.entries(attributes).forEach(([attr, val]) => {
    elt.setAttribute(attr, val);
  });
  elt.append(...children);
  return elt;
};

const createBook = (movie) =>
  createElement(
    "div",
    { class: "book", "data-imdb-id": movie.imdbID },
    createElement(
      "figure",
      { class: "book__img_wrapper" },
      createElement("img", { class: "book_img", src: movie.Poster })
    ),
    createElement(
      "div",
      { class: "book__title" },
      `${movie.Title} - ${movie.Year}`
    ),
    createElement("div", { class: "book__ratings" }, movie.Type)
  );
```

Comment: I used the event listener and since im learning how to use js I dont have too much understanding using DOM

Answer (score 0):

You are using [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to generate HTML. In a template literal. `${x}` is replaced by the result of evaluation of the expression `x`. Thus,

```
return `<div class="book" onclick="showMoviePost(${movie.imdbID})">...`
```

results in the string

```
'return `<div class="book" onclick="showMoviePost(tt0104779)">...'
```

When you then use this as HTML and click on the resultant element, JavaScript tries to execute `showMoviePost(tt0104779)`, but to do that it has to know the value of the variable `tt0104779`, which obviously is not defined.

Instead, make sure you have the string in your code, rather than a bare identifier:

```
return `<div class="book" onclick="showMoviePost(${JSON.stringify(movie.imdbID)})">...`
```

You could also think you could just put quotes in there:

```
return `<div class="book" onclick="showMoviePost('${movie.imdbID}')">...`
```

... but that is not as safe — what if `movie.imdbID` has a quote character?

Comment: I use ur solution but now im getting: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (at index.html:1:15)

Comment: Yeah, I missed a quote. Edited.

Comment: Yes, it does. But rn is throwing another error with the solution that u gave me. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (at index.html:1:15)

Comment: There was another typo, which I now fixed. Hopefully that was it.